# SublimeREPL: mesg: ttyname: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: bash, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

When I try `source ~/.profile` in SublimeREPL for the bash shell I get the error above. Any ideas how to resolve this?

So this is the contents of my .profile. I start a bash instance inside bash I can source things normally.

```
##
# DELUXE-USR-LOCAL-BIN-INSERT
# (do not remove this comment)
##
echo $PATH | grep -q -s "/usr/local/bin"
if [ $? -eq 1 ] ; then
    PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
    export PATH
fi

test -r /sw/bin/init.sh && . /sw/bin/init.sh

# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

##
# Your previous /Users/jonathan/.profile file was backed up as /Users/jonathan/.profile.macports-saved_2013-05-18_at_17:57:46
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2013-05-18_at_17:57:46: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

### Added correct profile for Postgres
export PATH="Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # startup virtualenv-burrito
    if [ -f "$HOME/.venvburrito/startup.sh" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.venvburrito/startup.sh"
    fi
fi

### Added for Amazon CLI
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi

mesg n
```

Comment: Can you `source` another file with success?  What is the contents of your `.profile`?

Comment: I added the contents of my bash .profile. Yes, I can source other files.

Comment: what are the contents of `$HOME/.venvburrito/startup.sh`, `~/.bashrc`, and `/sw/bin/init.sh`?

Comment: BTW, this line `export PATH="Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"` should have a `/` in front of `Applications`